# Perl Regex: Adding a symbol in front of another symbol in a string

Tags: regex, perl

If i had a string:

```
my $string = "a/hello/bye/d";
```

I would like to add in a "\" symbol infront of every "/" symbol found inside the string. Are there any possible ways to do this?

Example:

```
$string = "a\/hello\/bye\/d";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the regular expression delimiter to a `|` and then substitute all forward slashes `/` with back-slash forward-slash `\/`.  The back-slash must be escaped, since it is itself the 'escape' character.  So `\\/`;  The trailing `g` means perform the replacement everywhere, the leading `s` means substitute:  `s|\|\\/|g`.

Have a read of [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc%20perlretut) for a friendly introduction to regular expressions.

```
my $string = "a/hello/bye/d";
$string =~ s|/|\\/|g;
print $string . "\n";
```

**output**

```
a\/hello\/bye\/d
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use quotemeta() to achieve that.

```
: perl -e 'my $string = "a/hello/bye/d"; print quotemeta($string); print "\n"'
a\/hello\/bye\/d
```